# Error in marketplace testkit When using Google analytics of codeplex

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-analytics

I am using Microsoft Silverlight Analytics Framework in my application to track the pages. Everything is working fine and I also get the values in GA website. But the problem is when I run the app in marketplace testkit I am getting the error "Pressing back button in "MainPage.xaml" does not close the dialog box".

```
 <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>       
 <shell:PhoneApplicationService 
        Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" 
        Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
    <local:AnalyticsService WebPropertyId="UA-1234-1" />
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

But When I remove local:AnalyticsService from file its not giving an error.

Guys help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys I got the issue in msaf source code. In Microsoft.WebAnalytics.WP7 project and filename - WebAnalyticsService.cs they are using a popup and they are not closing the popup. If you close the popup then the project will pass marketplace. But I am not sure where to close the popup.